# How do I export styles from a Microsoft Word 2003 .dot file?

Tags: ms-word

I have an old .dot file with a few dozen styles in it.
I need to place them into **another .dot file**  that I received.  Is there a better way to get them in there than manually recreating each style?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a 'Style Organizer' tool within Word which will let you copy styles from one document to another if they are both open at once.

In Word 2007:

- Open the styles dialog (Home tab -> Styles -> Bottom Right button).
- Click the 'manage styles' button.
- Click 'Import/Export...'

I can't remember what the option is in Word 2003. I think it was Tools -> Style Organizer or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Quick MSO 2003 tip for transferring styles from the current document to another document.  The Organizer UI shows the currently open document on the left and Normal.dot on the right.  Hitting the dropdown on the right doesn't give you anything other than Normal.dot.  Quoi??

Hit the right hand Close File button.  This will then be replaced by an Open File ... command button.  Select any file you want to from there.  Mind the file type.  MSOs defaiult is .dot.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Styles" tab in the "Organizer" (menu "Tools" -> "Templates and Add-Ins" -> "Organizer") to copy the styles.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to transfer your styles & formatting between two documents:

1. `Go to Tools > Templates & Add-Ins...`
2. `Click Organizer button...`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Laura's answer helped me to find it in MS Word 2003. I clicked on Tools, Templates and Add-Inns, Organizer, then Styles. I just highlighted what I wanted from either side and click on Copy.

Thanks Laura. Which I could vote you up.